# What is the SQL query for deleting all posts in Trash?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am using WP 3.7.1. I have almost 2000 posts in my Trash category of WordPress posts and I want to delete all the posts in Trash. Can anyone tell what is the SQL query for that? My table prefix is tscms_

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but I could understand..

Comment: What is trash is it a column in ur database

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi - if the OP does not know what a schema is - it is really better not to touch SQL - wordpress has much easier ways of doing it .

Answer (score 8):

If uncomfortable with SQL, you can update your WordPress configuration file, `wp-config.php` with [this line](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Empty_Trash):

```
// Empty the trash every 30 days
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 30 );
```

You can totally disable trash by setting the number of days to zero - meaning WordPress will no longer ask for confirmation when someone clicks on "Delete Permanently":

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0 );
```

To empty the trash using SQL, after backing up your data if appropriate:

```
DELETE p
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
WHERE post_status = 'trash'
```

For all CPT:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'trash'
```

In your example, you will need to swap the default `wp_` in `wp_posts` for database `prefix`, making `tscms_posts`.